# The menu list won't display after scrolling up or down

Tags: html, css

Goal:
The menu list included the text "Coffee, Tea and Milk" should display when you scroll down or up.

Problem:
The menu list Coffee, Tea and Milk won't display after using scroll up and down.
What part am I missing?

[image]

JSbin:
https://jsbin.com/rinewiduyi/edit?html,css,js,output

Thank you!

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
              <div id="testtest">
                <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
              </div>
              <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
                <li class="title">Coffee</li>
                <li class="title">Tea</li>
                <li class="title">Milk</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="palette-2">
                content
                <br />
                              content
                <br />
                              content
                      <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                       <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                        <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                 <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                             <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
                <br />                content
            </div>
            <div id="footer" class="palette-4">
                footer
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
body {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
    background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
    background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 { 
    background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 { 
    background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
    grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
    grid-area: footer;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "left-header header right-header"
      "left-content content right-content"
      "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;    
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }  
  
  #top-content {
    /*    */

    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }  
  
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }

  ul.nav-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;

  }

  ul.nav-menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }  
}            


@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {

  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "content"
      "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }    
  
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }

  ul.nav-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;

  }

  ul.nav-menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }  
  
  #content {

  }
  
}
```

---

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    scrollFunction();
};

// get initial pageYOffset value
let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

function scrollFunction() {
  
    // current pageYOffset value
    const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;
          
    if (curOffset - originOffset > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
      // down
      document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";  

    } else {
      // up
      document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "0";
    }
    // change originOffset value every time
    originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

---

Comment: I can see the menu when I run the code, then when I scroll the picture goes on top of the menu. so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please take a look at the picture and I also have updated the content with new info

Comment: one more question if you don't mind. why did you use `pageoffset`? what exactly do you want js code to do? I think there might be a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your problem. actually @Vijay Hardaha answer is correct. but let me add a little detail.

the menu is actually there but its container height is not enough to show it because in your `@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px` you set `height: 50px` for `top-content`. but you give it 200px in the other media query, so it actually works in screens smaller than 1000px.

the other issue is that your default display for `top-content` is flex but you set it to block in js code, and each display will give a different result.

so give it enough `height` in the CSS or use your default style in js code which is `flex`.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

// get initial pageYOffset value
let originOffset = window.pageYOffset;

function scrollFunction() {

  // current pageYOffset value
  const curOffset = window.pageYOffset;

  if (curOffset - originOffset > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    // down
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "-50px";

  } else {
    // up
    document.getElementById('top-content').style.display = 'block'; // change this to flex
    document.getElementById("top-content").style.marginTop = "0";
  }
  // change originOffset value every time
  originOffset = window.pageYOffset;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.palette-1 {
  background-color: #83B2FF;
}

.palette-2 {
  background-color: #8BF18B;
}

.palette-4 {
  background-color: #FF8650;
}

.palette-5 {
  background-color: #FF555E;
}

#content {
  grid-area: content;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "left-header header right-header" "left-content content right-content" "left-footer footer right-footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1000px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px; /* changed this from 50 to bigger height   */
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #content {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  #container {
    background-color: #FFE981;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header" "content" "footer";
    row-gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #8cffa0;
  }
  #top-content {
    grid-area: header;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-top: 3px solid #425c62;
  }
  #asdfasdf {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.nav-menu {
    margin: 0;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    border-top: 1px solid #83B2FF;
  }
  ul.nav-menu>li:hover {
    background-color: #2779BF;
    border-top: 1px solid #425c62;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top-content" class="palette-1">
      <div id="testtest">
        <img src="https://www.logolynx.com/images/logolynx/1f/1fa1c2a2ea0d69a85215d878f3a0652a.jpeg" width="100px" height="45px" />
      </div>
      <ul id="iconmenu" class="nav-menu">
        <li class="title">Coffee</li>
        <li class="title">Tea</li>
        <li class="title">Milk</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="palette-2">
      content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
      <br /> content
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="palette-4">
      footer
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Menus are still there but since you're setting `display: block;` from JS but your design system works with `display: flex;` in that case, your header doesn't show menu inline and as it became `block` it will wrap the menu below the logo. and since you have `height: 50px` and `overflow: hidden` the are hidden under the overflow.